# How do you create (and read) windows shortcut(.lnk file) in Java?

Tags: java, windows, shortcut

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234231/how-do-you-create-an-application-shortcut-lnk-file-in-c-or-net), different langauge.

How do you do it in Java? Do you use JNI? run exe? or are there any library read/write *.lnk like POI read/write *.xls?

I used to workaround to create ".url" which is [plain text INI file](http://www.fmtz.com/formats/url-file-format/article). But I am looking for other interesting way to do it.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java ! References in mentioned thread (Same question) are usefull here too!!

Comment: for lack of better answers could you explain  the trick you do with .url ?

Comment: @pvgoddijn please read http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a JNI interface if the goal is quality.

http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/

For quick hacks, (on my workstation only) : System.Exec() a vbscript :-) (I know, i know).

Comment: Not only does the supplied .dll not support x64, but **jshortcut** is GPL

Comment: Looks like it's LGPL now, and they claim 64-bit support on a contributed version via github (didn't test it out though)