# How to create a .lnk file on the desktop using Java?

Tags: java

How can I create a `.lnk` file using Java? such as I want to create a .lnk file on my desktop which opens the following directory `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`. I have found [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0660.html) website  but it is for creating an URL for the website shortcut. it basically write out 2 lines ([`InternetShortcut`] and
`URL = XXXXXX.com`) by using `FileWriter` and save it as .URL file. but it seems not working with lnk  extension.

Comment: I was going to say it would be a fun exercise to build your own .link in binary and write it out to that directory. But there is a whole lot more to .lnk files than I would ever have expected.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx

Comment: See [Creating a shortcut file from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145942/creating-a-shortcut-file-from-java)

Comment: Whatever the working method you'll find, it obviously won't be portable...

Comment: Faced with the same problem, I ended up using [this program](http://ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html) embedded in the jar file which I copy to the user's home directory at runtime and call with the appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *.symlink file. It works too, and it is simple to create.

Here is a short Java snippet to create a *.symlink file:

```java
// Link target
Path targetPath = Path.of("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe");
// Link destination
// You can replace Calculator with your own file name (without extension).
Path linkPath = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/Calculator");
Files.createSymbolicLink(linkPath, targetPath);
```