# NIO.2 Path.toRealPath problem

Tags: java

I have the following code where ac.lnk point to c:\t.txt

```
Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\joshua\\Desktop\\ac.lnk");
Path _rp = p.toRealPath();
```

but _rp doesn't contain the path with he symbolic link expanded to c:\t.txt

I read from the doc http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath that only if I use as argument `LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS` then `realPath` does not resolve symbolic links.

Thanks.

Comment: You have 68 questions without an accepted answer. :P

Comment: Yes, I promise you that, as soon as possible, I'll answer them! :)

Comment: Not all answers are not acceptable, but a lot of questions without an unaccepted answer is not just bad luck. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ac.lnk is an executable file known as a shortcut, not a symbolic link. Windows Explorer can read the path in the file and pretend its a link.

Perhaps what you are looking for a Shortcut reader.

[Windows shortcut (.lnk) parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java)

[How do you create (and read) windows shortcut(.lnk file) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343776/how-do-you-create-and-read-windows-shortcut-lnk-file-in-java)

Comment: Ok thanks. If I use mklink from the shell it creates a real symbolic link!