# How to access recently opened files in Windows 8?

Tags: java, windows, windows-8

How does one access the list of recently opened files in Windows 8 using Java?

In other words, what is the path for the "recent document" folder in Windows, which could be passed as argument in constructor of file class to access the files in that folder?

Comment: Probably no such path exists, but I am sure there has to be some other way to access the recently opened files.

Comment: so what is that way, for what u r so sure?

Comment: it probably is a native api in windows

Comment: how to use that into my program? i want to make a program which takes a record of all the PDF files opened recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look here -

- MS Office Docs - `C:\Users\YouAccount\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office\Recent`
- Opened by Explorer - `C:\Users\YouAccount\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`

To get the actual path by link - see these topics:

- [NIO.2 Path.toRealPath problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424895/nio-2-path-torealpath-problem)
- [Windows shortcut (.lnk) parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java)
- [How do you create (and read) windows shortcut(.lnk file) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343776/how-do-you-create-and-read-windows-shortcut-lnk-file-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

It is always inside `%USERPROFILE%\Recent`, so using `System.env(argument)`

```
String userProfileDir = System.getenv("USERPROFILE")+"\\Recent";
```

should do the trick.