# update windows shortcut icon in Java

Tags: java, windows, icons, shortcut

How can one change the icon image of a pre-existing shortcut through java?  I do not want to change the icon image of a java executable, but have a java program that changes a shortcut's icon image.

I know I can manually change the icon image by right clicking on a shortcut and going to properties->shortcut->change icon, but I would like to do this through java.

Answer (score 1):

Its impractical do this in pure java yourself, although the lnk-file format is documented by microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd871305.aspx), but since it originated with Win95 it underwent significant extensions and redefinitions over the years. Implementing this seems like a daunting task.

You can try to find a library that implements it for you, e.g. http://ovanttasks.sourceforge.net/ov-native/ may do what you want.

The alternative would be to use existing Windows API's to do the job (See [How do you create (and read) windows shortcut(.lnk file) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343776)).