# Best strategy for installing cygwin under restrictive IT policies?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, group-policy

My organization has a group policy in effect that will only allow executable programs to reside under the Program Files (or Program Files X86) directory. Obviously, these directories are not writable by normal users. I have access to local admin rights, so I can install things there if I want. But of course it doesn't make sense to put the whole cygwin tree there, since users need to be able to write to /home, /tmp, etc. I am thinking I might be able to do something with links, maybe install to c:\cygwin, then move just the /bin directory under Program Files and create a hard link to it?

Has anyone run into a similar situation and come up with an elegant solution? This is Win 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Similar question and answer is on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343988/accessing-a-cygwin-symlink-from-windows. I'm not sure that is best or not, but the anwser is scored 6.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: What exactly do you mean by that? Are you expecting the user-space `cygwin1.dll` to provide real security or something? Cygwin can only work with the mechanisms it finds on the platform. Cygwin files can be protected via NTFS ACLs, for example, and the OS kernel will enforce those.

Comment: Actually, it didn't take long to find this: "As of version 1.5.13, the Cygwin developers are not aware of any feature in the cygwin dll that would allow users to gain privileges or to access objects to which they have no rights under Windows."  So the problem no longer exists.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Cygwin 1.5.13 is [nearly a decade gone now](ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2005/03/01/122116/index.html). Anyway, my point about Cygwin being purely user space is that you can't expect it to enforce things like, say, [read-only shared memory](http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open). The shared memory is in all Cygwin process's memory space, so there's no barrier the Cygwin DLL could impose that the process dynamically linked to it could not get around.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: that stands to reason, doesn't it?  There's never any security between different parts of the same process in Windows, and AFAIK the same is true of UNIX.  I was talking about security between processes belonging to different users.  But it's all moot anyway, since it turns out my information was thoroughly out of date.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: even so, I'm not keen on Cygwin; for one thing, it [plays nasty games to implement fork](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.api.fork) and is [inclined to compatibility issues](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda) as a result.  (That isn't because the Cygwin developers messed up; there isn't any good way to implement fork() in a Windows process.)  I would always recommend either properly porting the necessary application(s) or using a virtual machine.  But YMMV, and there are undoubtedly plenty of scenarios where the advantages of Cygwin outweigh the disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Cygwin 1.7.34, solving such problems required a fair bit of hoop-jumping,¹ but now it's easy:

1. If you haven't installed Cygwin yet, do so.²

   If you have Cygwin installed already and you started with a version of Cygwin prior to 1.7.34, move `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` out of the way,³ then upgrade to the current version.
2. Start the Cygwin Terminal.
3. Open Cygwin's `/etc/nsswitch.conf` in your favorite text editor.⁴ Add a line like this:

   ```
   db_home: /%H
   ```

That's it! When you next re-start Cygwin, it will treat your Windows  profile directory as your Cygwin home directory.⁵ This means you will have useful sub-folders like `Desktop` and `Downloads` as sub-folders, which matches the way OS X and a lot of desktop Linuxes work.

Some people might not want these two directories to be treated as equivalents. You can choose any path scheme you like. For example, you could change it to `/cygdrive/c/Users/%U/cygwin` to put your Cygwin home folder into a `cygwin` subdirectory of your Windows profile directory.

This new feature of Cygwin is very powerful and [can do a lot more than I show here](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html). For example, you can change a Cygwin user home directory via AD instead, if you like. See that documentation for details.

You might also want to rearrange a few other elements of the Cygwin path scheme. You can do so by editing [Cygwin's `/etc/fstab`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table) file. You probably want to move `/tmp`, `/usr/tmp`, and `/var/tmp` to a directory that non-admin users can write to, for one thing:

```
c:/tmp  /tmp      ntfs  auto  0 0
c:/tmp  /usr/tmp  ntfs  auto  0 0
c:/tmp  /var/tmp  ntfs  auto  0 0
```

This will let you install (and later update) Cygwin as an Administrator while still letting unprivileged users run Cygwin. This makes Cygwin behave more like Linux or Unix. Since most software in the Cygwin package repository comes from that world, you can count on it to behave correctly under such a scheme.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. The [first version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26667108/1) tells you how to do an equivalent thing with older versions of Cygwin.
2. Cygwin doesn't care where you install it, so if the default doesn't work for you, feel free to change it. Some ideas:

   - `C:\Program Files\Cygwin`
   - `C:\Users\jeremy\Cygwin`
   - `D:\cygwin`

   Cygwin will remember your choice on subsequent updates.
3. If you don't move these files out of the way, they interfere with the solution we build above. This part of Cygwin is complex enough to deserve [a whole section in the Cygwin user manual](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html). Hint. :)
4. Cygwin installs a stripped-down version of the Vim text editor by default.

   If you don't like `vi`, there are many other text editors in the Cygwin package repository.

   If you *do* like `vi`, I suggest installing the full version of Vim, then adding `alias vi=vim` to your `~/.bashrc`.

   You can also use a native Windows GUI text editor. Cygwin's `/etc/nsswitch.conf` parser appears to cope with DOS line endings.
5. The Cygwin DLL is building this path from the `%HOMEDRIVE%` and `%HOMEPATH%` environment variables, then converting it to POSIX form.