execvp: Argument list too long
I'm working with Cygwin in Windows XP (through virtual machine), with a legacy project that I was given to try figuring out. When trying to build the code (several snapshots/revisions), it fails when trying to link the thousands of .o files. I get the error:
make: execvp: C:\project\tools\maketool.exe: Argument list too long
The command in the script is basically like
maketool.exe (long list of arguments including the tons of .o files)
It's apparently a hard limit set by the OS. I was told these code snapshots were able to be built back in the day (nearly 20 years ago from now). But there's no documentation, so I'm trying to figure out what my options are.
I read about xargs which runs a command multiple times with sets of arguments; but not sure if the linking process will succeed if it's done in divisions/steps. There are also other arguments that need to be specified, unrelated to linking, as part of the same command.
There was also a mention of replacing the common directory path to the .o files with a symlink instead. Could this work?
What workarounds might they have used? What can I do to get around this?

If the files have long paths, move them to a different directory with a shorter name. Are you forced to use Windows? (You tagged this both [tag:linux] and [tag:cygwin] but it cannot be both.)

Sorry, that's my mistake. Slip of the mind as I'm thinking of the shell and "Linux" kicked in. I am restricted to Windows, yeah. Can the path to the files be substituted with something like a symbolic link?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343988/accessing-a-cygwin-symlink-from-windows seems to imply that there is a hack of sorts, with caveats. Alternatively, run multiple commands to copy all the dependent files into a/ and hope that this is sufficient to get you below the limit.

There's nothing you can do about this problem using only shell commands, because make can't invoke a shell containing all the files due to these restrictions.  You have to use a batch file; most tools allow you to give an argument that begins with an @ and the tool will consider that to be the name of a file containing arguments, instead of an argument.
Then the question becomes, how to create such a file... you can't do it with shell operations for the same reason you can't run the command itself.
If you have a sufficiently-new version of GNU Make you can use make's $(file ...) function to have make itself write the file; since you're not invoking a shell the shell's environment limits don't come into play.

One could conceivably create an arguments file via a shell command that did not require the individual file names to appear as command-line arguments.  A find command, for example.  Or perhaps the filenames could go into a heredoc.

"the filenames in a heredoc" is basically what I'm suggesting above, but created with GNU Make's $(file ...) command.  Agreed, if you don't need to have the list of files driven directly from the values of variables in your makefile you can use some other method of generating those files like a shell command or whatever.  But if you, for example, have a bunch of files in your directory that make a library and a separate bunch of files in the same directory that make an executable and there's no common distinction based on filename etc., it will be hard to use find etc.
