# Windows shortcut (.lnk .url) parser for shortcut URL's

Tags: java, windows, url, shortcut

I've been using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java/672775#672775) to parse a windows shortcut and determine what the shortcut points to.  However, it only works for local files and network shares.
Windows shortcuts can also point to URLs.  The solution I've been using does not parse URL shortcuts correctly. Any idea why or how to fix it?

For me, it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at this line:

```
int file_location_info_flag = link[file_start + file_location_info_flag_offset_offset];
```

I've been testing with a shortcut named "C:\googleshort.url" that points to http://www.google.com/. Clicking on the shortcut works just fine and brings up google, but the java parser fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the .url file in a text editor it has the following content:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974151/windows-shortcut-lnk-url-parser-for-shortcut-urls
```

Should be easy enough to parse.