# Windows Shortcut lnk parser for Java

Tags: java, windows, shortcut, lnk

I am trying to grab the target value in a `.lnk` file and have tried using the methods specified in an older [post here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java/25501224#25501224):

Unfortunately the code does not seem to work on some lnk files. The sample of the `.lnk` I am testing this on is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c start test.vbs&start explorer GRE&exit
```

The value that is being returned is always null. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The mentionned solution allos one to process `.lnk` files the same way symbolic links are processed on Linux. But the .lnk file you're showing there do not open a file : it instead executes some commands and return the result. This will require a different kind of processing. In fact, you'll have to modify the `lnk` parser to detect if file is in fact a command, then run that command and grab the command result.

in other words : here you don't want to open a file, but launch a command, which, under Windows, OS, is not the same kind of operation.