# How to get the target path of any shortcut file in windows in java program?

Tags: java

I have also created VBScript file but it doesn't turns out to be helpful.Is there any way that i can get the absolute path of shortcut(.lnk) files in my java program?

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I know, there isn't any way to do this with the JSE API. 
There are a few libraries around that allow you to read and create Windows shortcuts. Most of these use JNI. One example is JShortcut (http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~jimmc/jshortcut/).

Java.nio.file has methods to handle symbolic links but .lnk files are not really symbolic links in windows and I think this wont work with java.nio.files.

Also check out this stack overflow question :
[Windows shortcut (.lnk) parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java)