# How to extract associated icon from a File

Tags: java, image, file, extract, jlabel

I have an array of files -

```
File[] files = new File[9]
```

The files extensions are ".lnk" (Windows shortcut files) and I'm wondering how to extract the Image (The actual executable icon that you see in windows explorer...) from each file to set it to a `JLabel` ? Can anyone help me please?

Ive googled and stacked my overflows but I can only find C# or C++ examples or java examples on setting the icon :/

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java

Comment: @nafas Thank you, I didnt find what I was looking for on the link you gave but I found a link on the page you gave a link to that gave me what I was looking for xD So I have you to thank for the first link :P Here's the link I found http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Windows shortcut (.lnk) parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java)" –  nafas"

@nafas Thank you, I didnt find what I was looking for on the link you gave but I found a link on the page you gave a link to that gave me what I was looking for xD So I have you to thank for the first link :P Here's the link I found rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0439.html –  Piston Block