# Java - read details like name, path, size from shortcut on desktop

Tags: java, shortcut

Is it possible the read the information/details of a shortcut on desktop with java? I mean the details like name, type, file size, path, creation date, changed date,...

Comment: See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html). Give path of the desktop, iterate over all files, check if File is a regular file. If it is, get the Metadata that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows shortcut is a file itself, so accessing it as a file a good starting point.

To actually retrieve information related to the resource the shortcut points to, check the examples from:

- [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html)
- [Windows shortcut (.lnk) parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java)
- [Parsing Windows Shortcuts (lnk) files in java](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.java.help/ouFHsH1UgKI)