# Check if File / Path is Alias, Shortcut or Symbolic link

Tags: java, file-io

I need to traverse files in a folder, and find all images. I need to include subdirectories, as well as made shortcuts (on windows), aliases (for mac users) or symbolic links.

I found working API that only works for the symbolic links.. I can't seem to determine if a file is an Alias or a shortcut..

Code I have:

```
private List<Path> getFiles(String folder) throws IOException {

    List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(folder))) {
        
    
        
        for (Path p : stream) {
             
            System.out.println(p);
            if(isLink(p.toFile())) {
                
                files.addAll(getFiles(p.toFile().getCanonicalPath()));
            }
            
            
            
            String mimeType = Files.probeContentType(p);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(mimeType) && mimeType.contains("image")) {
                files.add(p);
            }

        }
    return files;
    }
```

and

```
public static boolean isLink(File file) {
    try {
        if (!file.exists())
            return true;
        else {

            String cnnpath = file.getCanonicalPath();
            String abspath = file.getAbsolutePath();
            return !abspath.equals(cnnpath);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `toFile()` calls you could also use `Files.isSymbolicLink(Path p)` and `p.toRealPath()` to determine the target of symbolic links for the paths you use.

Windows shortcuts are not modelled in Java File / Path APIs. An implementation which reads Windows shortcut binary format can be found here in [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java) - it better if using drive letters not using UNC pathnames.

I can't help for MacOS alias.

You should keep track of the directories visited in getFiles to avoid infinite loop when following links.